# How can I vertically align an Image in a div/span?

Tags: html

I've created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8uWv/

I'm trying to vertically align the image in the middle of the`div`. Using `vertical-align: middle` isn't working. In additon to that I've tried `margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto` but still no luck. How can I get this image centered vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `vertical-align:middle;` you'll need to add `display:table-cell;` to the container `<div>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/XXE2j/

Answer (score 2):

Add line-height: 200px; to the div in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the best article about vertical centering
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/